# Which java desktop gui package is best for a blind programmer

Tags: accessibility

If I am a blind programmer, Which java Gui package can I use for the developement of an desktop application? It meance the package should be accessable with keyboard! I thing most of the professional programmers are using netbeen for their job. but it not supportable with JAWS or NVDA screen reader softwares! here I am asking about the package which can design through handwriten codes like CSS in wev programming.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse will be well suited for a blind programmer. A flawless coding though will be a key to success.

Comment: Yess I know that but It's an IDE only I Am asking about the package like swing javafx any other ....!